# Semicontinuity of the Lebesgue measure of images of a family of functions

Tags: real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry

Let $\mu$ be the usual Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^m$. Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ is uniformly continuous, and let $U$ be a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The question is:

> Is the function $\Omega:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[0,\infty]$ defined by $\Omega(t)=\mu(f(U\times\{t\}))$ necessarily lower semicontinuous? How about if $U$ is compact?

An example arises from letting $n=2$ and $m=1$, and letting $f(\mathbf{p},t)$ be the projection of $\mathbf{p}$ onto the line $L_t$ through the origin and $(\cos t,\sin t)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (precomposed with an isomorphism $L_t\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$). In this example, if $U=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x\in\mathbb{Q}\}$, then $\Omega$ is not *upper* semicontinuous since $\Omega(t)=\infty$ unless $t$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$, in which case $\Omega(t)=0$.

In this vein, a more specific version of the question is:

> If $f$ is bilinear, then is $\Omega$ (as defined above) necessarily lower semicontinuous?

Note one can show that if $U$ is compact, then $\Omega$ is *upper* semicontinuous.

**Proof:** For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\gamma>0$ so that the union $\mathcal V$ of open balls of radius $\gamma$ centered at points of $f(U\times\{t_0\})$ has measure no more than $\epsilon$ greater than the measure of $f(U\times\{t_0\})$ by Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem. Then because $f$ is uniformly continuous, there exists a $\delta>0$ so that $\Vert f(x,t)-f(x,t_0)\Vert<\gamma$ whenever $|t-t_0|<\delta$, and thus $f(U\times\{t\})$ is a subset of $\mathcal V$.

Comment: Does the following work: let $g_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a sequence of smooth approximations converging uniformly to a space-filling curve $g : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ whose image is the unit square.  Let $f(x,t) = g_n(x)$ when $t=1/n$, $f(x,0) = g(x)$, and interpolating linearly between these points.  Then $f : [0,1]^2 \to [0,1]^2$ is uniformly continuous (I think?), with $\Omega(t) = 0$ for $t > 0$ and $\Omega(0) = 1$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I think your example works (for Hilbert's space-filing curve, e.g. the standard approximations $g_n$ converge uniformly to $g$, and $g$ is uniformly continuous, so $f$ would be uniformly continuous). Thank you!

Comment: I've updated the question to include a variation on the question in which $f$ is bilinear; @NateEldredge's comment answers the more general version of the question.